# How can I delete some strange squares that appears in my blender?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, blender, ubuntu-drivers

I had installed blender in my Ubuntu 14.04, but, when I add any figure, it appears some strange black squares.
[image: This are the strange squares]

I had installed blender using this comands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

And my graphic target is : 
Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)

This are my drivers:
[image]

Comment: This may be a graphics issue... could you please [edit] into your question how you installed blender (and which version), and also what graphics are you using (you can find stuff like the card names and drivers using `lspci -v` for that)

Comment: I have editet the question with all you said

Comment: Please check you're using the proprietary drivers. Go to Configurations > Additional Drivers. Case not, I suggest you to use.

Comment: Which driver i have to chose ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the active driver:
[image: This is the panel where we can change the active driver]

You have to try different drivers and **restart the computer every time you change the driver**